Unable to solve/reduce geometric Brownian motion inequality
I am trying to solve a few inequalities like the one below for Z:
S * Exp[(mu - sigma^2/2)*T + Sqrt[T]*sigma*Z] > k

Manually, I can work out the solution easily, which is:
Z > (Log[k/S] - (mu - sigma^2/2)*T)/(Sqrt[T]*sigma)

However, when I use Mathematica with Solve, it returns an empty solution {}. Then I tried using Reduce, adding simplifying assumptions and even adding the Reals domain:
Reduce[{S*Exp[(mu - sigma^2/2)*T + Sqrt[T]*sigma*Z] > k, S > 0, k > 0, T > 0, sigma > 0}, Z, Reals]

But this returns quite an unreadable solution (see screenshot below). Is there a way to get Mathematica to reduce this inequality to the simplified version I have above? I am probably using Solve or Reduce wrongly. Any help appreciated.


What is the reason to change the title? Brownian motion is off-topic here.

@user64494 Because a previous user asked what GBM meant. So I thought it's better to clarify.

I see the following way.
ineq = PowerExpand[Log[S*Exp[(mu - sigma^2/2)*T + Sqrt[T]*sigma*Z]] > Log[k]]


(mu - sigma^2/2) T + sigma Sqrt[T] Z + Log[S] > Log[k]

Reduce[b > 0 && ineq /. {(mu - sigma^2/2)   T -> a, 
sigma*Sqrt[T] -> b}, Z] /. {a -> (mu - sigma^2/2)   T, 
b -> sigma*Sqrt[T]}


((mu - sigma^2/2) T | Log[k] | Log[S]) \[Element] Reals &&  sigma Sqrt[T] > 0 &&  Z > (-((mu - sigma^2/2) T) + Log[k] - Log[S])/(sigma Sqrt[T])


Simpler Reduce[S*Exp[a + b*Z] > k && b > 0 && k > 0, Z, Reals] with the same a and b.
